# Make all fields hidden for a form

Tags: django, forms, model, hidden

How to 'hide' all fields in a form based on a model class in django? There is the hidden widget which can be set on the form, but this solution makes me copy all fields from the model into the form.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Model._meta.get_all_field_names()` gives you a list of the names which you can use to build the `widget` dictionary on a `ModelForm.Meta`:

```
class TestForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Test
        widgets = {field_name: forms.HiddenInput() 
                   for field_name in Test._meta.get_all_field_names()}
```

Comment: Python 2.6 version:  `widgets = dict((field_name, forms.HiddenInput()) for field_name in Test._meta.get_all_field_names())`